# Have existed vs. To have existed

Tags: grammar, tense, present-perfect, grammaticality-in-context, infinitive-phrases

I want to know that: does the perfect tense function it proper usage when it preceded by “to” infinitive.

I was taught that we couldn’t put “ago” with present perfect.

So, I came across a sentence such as the following:

> - These lions seem **to have existed** 70 years **ago**

Isn’t the same as?:

> - These lions have existed 70 years ago. **incorrect**

---

[Warning:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/ago) Cambridge Dictionary

We normally use ago with the past simple. We don’t use it with the present perfect:

I received his letter four days ago.

Not: I have received his letter four days ago. Incorrect

---

[The source](https://www.google.jo/amp/s/www.newscientist.com/article/sumatran-tigers-fall-17-per-cent-just-two-strongholds/amp/)

> - Luskin’s team found that there are now only two habitats with viable populations, down from the 12 thought **to have existed** 70 years **ago**.

Comment: **ago** is fine with the perfect infinitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain this to myself, and maybe it will make sense to you :)

With the present perfect, the temporal *origo* is the speaker's *Now*, and we  cannot use **ago** with the present perfect, because **ago** excludes The Now.

However, with the present perfect infinitive, the *origo* is free-floating (the infinitive being non-finite): it can be projected into the future or into the past:

> To have existed in a world without elephants may well be the fate of
>   people living only 50 years from now.
>
> The Yeti is believed to have sent telegrams to Sasquatch 100 years ago.

Comment: It definitely makes sense. I, totally, got your point of explanation that present perfect doesn’t act like it has a specific time when it comes with to-infinite.

Answer (score 1):

"seem to have existed" has nothing to do with the present perfect. The sentence:

> These lions seem to have existed 70 years ago

is equivalent to:

> It appears that / Apparently these lions **existed** 70 years ago.

The perfect infinitive (formed by "(to) have + past participle") refers to the past and can thus take any adverbial typical of the past tense. Other examples:

- He must **have arrived** yesterday. (I conclude/infer that he **arrived** yesterday.)
- He happens to **have arrived** earlier than expected. (It turns out that he **arrived** earlier than expected.)

As you can see, the perfect infinitive accompanies modals or expressions that can indicate the speaker's **current** attitude or view in regard to a **past** event, and this enables the perfect infinitive to take past adverbials.

Comment: The "past" of the perfect infinitive can be in the future, as it is a *relative* past.   *It **will be** a source of great pride for her to have argued before the Supreme Court .*   She might be arguing before the Court tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> These lions seem to have existed 70 years ago

The perfect infinitive is formed with *to have* + the *-ed* form of a verb: *to have existed*.

The perfect infinitive is used after another verb: *seem* in your first example.

Or, as in the source:

> Luskin’s team found that there are now only two habitats with viable populations, down from the 12 **thought** to have existed 70 years ago.

The verb here is *thought*, followed by the perfect infinitive, and *thought* is the past simple that you see with *ago*.

This phrase has a relatively complex construction, with multiple components and verb conjugations:

> Luskin's team **found** / (that) there **are** now only two habitats with viable populations, / down from the 12 **thought** + **to have existed** 70 years ago.

The first clause/phrase has the simple past *found*, the second has the present *are* and the third has the simple past *thought* with the perfect infinitive *to have existed*.

If it helps, the sentence could be rewritten as:

> Luskin's team found that there are now only two habitats with viable populations. Luskin's team thinks that 70 years ago there were 12 habitats with viable populations.

Comment: "thought" is not past tense but past participle and is most probably the abridged form of the relative clause "that **are** thought". The main verb in that verb phrase is then "are", which is present. What accounts for the use of "70 years ago" is the perfect infinitive "have existed", not the passive present from which the past participle derives. If the relative were "that **were"" thought", then the adverbial would be ambiguous: that was the belief 70 years ago, or the lions existed 70 years ago.

Comment: You are mistaken. Here *thought* is simple past. The past participle would need to be conjugated with *to have*.

Comment: "thought" is beyond any doubt the participle of the passive in that sentence: *12 habitats (that **are) thought** to have existed 70 years ago).*